# Linking error LNK2019 in MSVC, unresolved symbols with __imp__ prefix, but should be from static lib

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, dllimport, lnk2019, imp

I'm running into linking problems in MSVC for a project that I wrote for g++. Here's the problem:

I build libssh as a static library as part of my application, adding the target in cmake with

add_library(ssh_static STATIC $libssh_SRCS)

Libssh is in C, so I have 'extern "C" {...}' wrapping the includes in my c++ sources. I then link the ssh_static target to my executable, sshconnectiontest, with

target_link_libraries(sshconnectiontest ... ssh_static ...)

This all works fine in linux with gcc, but now in MSVC I get

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__[function names here] referenced in [filename]
```

for every libssh function I use.

Any ideas whats going wrong? I've read somewhere that the **imp** prefix means that the linker is expecting to link a .dll, but this should not be the case since ssh_static is declared a static library in the add_library call...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From what I remember of my Windows days, in MinGW-built DLLs, the `__imp__` symbol prefix is used for the trampoline function that calls into the DLL proper. This symbol is then provided by a small static library with the extension `.dll.a`.

When you include libssh headers, you need to set a `#define` to indicate that you're expecting to link statically. If you don't, the libssh functions in the header will be declared `__declspec(dllimport)` and so the `__imp__` symbols will be expected at link time.

I had a look at the libssh source and found this at the top of `libssh.h`:

```
#ifdef LIBSSH_STATIC
  #define LIBSSH_API
#else
  #if defined _WIN32 || defined __CYGWIN__
    #ifdef LIBSSH_EXPORTS
      #ifdef __GNUC__
        #define LIBSSH_API __attribute__((dllexport))
      #else
        #define LIBSSH_API __declspec(dllexport)
      #endif
    #else
      #ifdef __GNUC__
        #define LIBSSH_API __attribute__((dllimport))
      #else
        #define LIBSSH_API __declspec(dllimport)
      #endif
    #endif
  #else
    #if __GNUC__ >= 4
      #define LIBSSH_API __attribute__((visibility("default")))
    #else
      #define LIBSSH_API
    #endif
  #endif
#endif
```

You need to define `LIBSSH_STATIC`, either through `#define` before the `#include <libssh.h>` line, or as a `/D` option. Since you're using CMake, you'll probably do this through `add_definitions` in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: That did it :-) I had set the flag when compiling libssh, but not for the other projects. Thanks!

Comment: Golden answer! Helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 12):

Don't know if it is your case, but the imp prefix may mean that you are compiling a x64 library in a Win32 project.

Comment: This was actually my problem on windows.  I was inadvertently linking a 64bit dll with a 32bit dll.

Comment: It is wrong if you chose  "Use MFC in a Static Library" option you will get the error back.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat late to the party, but I got the same error when mixing libraries with static and dynamic linkage to the CRT

Answer (score 0):

**Using a .DEF File**

If you choose to use __declspec(dllimport) along with a .DEF file, you should change the .DEF file to use DATA or CONSTANT to reduce the likelihood that incorrect coding will cause a problem:

```
// project.def
LIBRARY project
EXPORTS
   ulDataInDll   CONSTANT
```

The following table shows why:

```
Keyword      Emits in the import library   Exports
CONSTANT     _imp_ulDataInDll              _ulDataInDll
             _ulDataInDll                  

DATA         _imp_ulDataInDll              _ulDataInDll
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271769(v=vs.60).aspx

**BUT** CONSTANT is now deprecated

i found another way, in the .DEF file of exported .lib use :

```
 mainthreadid=_mainthreadid
```

and regenerate the lib with LIB.exe

in the import header file of the dll code...

```
extern "C" {
  extern const __declspec(dllexport) ulong mainthreadid;
}
```