# Code Blocks, MinGW, Boost, and static linking issues

Tags: c++, boost, static, mingw, codeblocks

I am using Code Blocks with MinGW and am trying to get a simple program to compile with static linking.  I have built the Boost libraries using [these directions](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef).  Everything worked out fine and I was able to successfully compile this simple program (it compiles, I know it doesn't work because it exits before the message is sent to the console, but I just want it to compile).

If I have a DLL in my linker libraries, it compiles fine, but when I switch it with the static .a libraries of the same contents, I get undefined references such as "undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6threadD1Ev'|".

I have no idea what the problem is and can't find the solution. I think it might have to do with linker settings but I can't find information on how to change them. I would be extremely grateful for any help that could be provided.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void myfunction()
{
    std::cout << "this is a thread" << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread mythread(&myfunction);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's from trying to link statically when the headers are configured for a dynamic link. I explain this for libssh in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704374/linking-error-lnk2019-in-msvc-unresolved-symbols-with-imp-prefix-but-should/3714112#3714112). Poking around in `boost/thread/detail/config.hpp` makes me think you should `#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB`, or use the `-D` flag to do the same.