# Problem linking c++ code using boost with mingw

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

I'm trying to port/build some of my code written for gcc (on linux) as a dll on windows. First I tried to build in under VC++ but there were so many errors/warnings (mainly in VC's own include files, which didn't really make much sense to me :)) so I installed MinGW distro (which includes Boost libraries). Compilation went quite smoothly, however linking failed with undefined references to functions from boost libraries. The "-t" parameter showed that the linker doesn't actually use the boost libraries for some reason (yes, the -L path is correct, the libraries are there, linker doesn't complain when I use -l).

After much googling I found out that the order is the problem, that I have to place my -l parameters after all my .o files (because of dependencies). This seemed to solve all the problems except one undefined reference to thread library. Again -t showed that this library is actually not used by the linker (not in the list) the others are (I use boost_system and boost_date_time as well). I played with the order of the parameters again but the result was the same. Any idea what am I missing?

The error is:

```
c:/x5/cpp/build//timed_cond.o:timed_cond.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6detail24basic_condition_variable7do_waitINS_11unique_lockINS_5mutexEEEEEbRT_NS0_7timeoutE[bool boost::detail::basic_condition_variable::do_wait<boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> > (boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&, boost::detail::timeout)]+0x246): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost11this_thread18interruptible_waitEPvNS_6detail7timeoutE'
```

I use same versions of Boost library (1.44.0) on both platforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. Looks like the problem is in boost libraries being static in MinGW-distro. Normally they are configured to be linked dynamically and that caused above issue. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705563/code-blocks-mingw-boost-and-static-linking-issues) answer explains it...