# g++ including boost library

Tags: c++, boost, g++, static-linking

i builded my boost library with bjam, and then moved all the `.a` files into `c:\Server\libs\boost_1_46_0\lib`

if i want to compile my program there is some error:

*the compile command*

`g++  -Ic:\Server\libs\boost_1_46_0\ -Lc:\Server\libs\boost_1_46_0\lib\ -lboost_thread-mgw45-mt-1_46 -o try1 try1.cpp`

*the errors*

```
C:\Users\FEHERG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccB46To7.o:try1.cpp:(.text+0xe9): undefined
 reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6thread4joinEv'
C:\Users\FEHERG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccB46To7.o:try1.cpp:(.text+0x120): undefine
d reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6threadD1Ev'
C:\Users\FEHERG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccB46To7.o:try1.cpp:(.text+0x138): undefine
d reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6threadD1Ev'
C:\Users\FEHERG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccB46To7.o:try1.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost11this_
thread18interruptible_waitEm[boost::this_thread::interruptible_wait(unsigned lon
g)]+0x40): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost11this_thread18interruptible_w
aitEPvNS_6detail7timeoutE'
C:\Users\FEHERG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccB46To7.o:try1.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6thread
C1IPFvvEEET_NS_10disable_ifINS_14is_convertibleIRS4_NS_6detail13thread_move_tIS4
_EEEEPNS0_5dummyEE4typeE[boost::thread::thread<void (*)()>(void (*)(), boost::di
sable_if<boost::is_convertible<void (*&)(), boost::detail::thread_move_t<void (*
)()> >, boost::thread::dummy*>::type)]+0x23): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5
boost6thread12start_threadEv'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

can anybody help me what is the problem in this problem?

*i followed this tutorial:* http://antonym.org/2009/05/threading-with-boost---part-i-creating-threads.html

so this is the source: http://pastebin.com/YqCPLNwU

**UPDATE:**

i think the error is not lining the library, the error is in the library.
i built it with bjam with `toolchain=gcc multithread` options.

**UPDATE**

here is the objdump http://pastebin.com/4fpqYb7d

**UPDATE**

i found that the problem is that the linker wants to link with dynamic linking or something like this.

[Code Blocks, MinGW, Boost, and static linking issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705563/code-blocks-mingw-boost-and-static-linking-issues)

there "Jack Kelly" says that i need to add `#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB` at the beginning of my source file. but this not helps to me. how can i link a library statically? (the `-static` not helped as well)

Comment: What is the content of try1.cpp?

Comment: updated my question! http://antonym.org/2009/05/threading-with-boost---part-i-creating-threads.html

Comment: try to compile with `-Wall`, maybe you'll get some additional useful warnings

Comment: nothing more. same errors with `-Wall` and `-Werror`

Comment: @omnosis: Try `objdump -t libboost_thread-mgw45-mt-1_46.a` or whatever is the dump utility in mingw. This should show you a (pretty long) list of functions which are exported in your `.a`. You can grep for the needed function there, to ensure that it's in.

Comment: i dont exactly understandd how to dump it. i didnt find any command for dumping a static library.

Comment: @omnosis: mingw package (which you seem to use) has objdump, hasn't it?

Comment: yes it has. i dumped the object with `objdump -t c:\Server \libs\boost_1_46_0\lib\libboost_thread-mgw45-mt-1_46.a >out.txt` -> http://pastebin.com/4fpqYb7d

Comment: @omnosis: You can see the archive contains `[466](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty  20)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x000070b0 __ZN5boost6thread4joinEv`, but not `_imp___ZN5boost6thread4joinEv`. So something is wrong with the library, perhaps it doesn't correspond to the headers/preprocessor switches you are using.

Comment: yes. now tryying to get a prebuild version of boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the -lboost_thread-mgw45-mt-1_46 option to the end of the command line (after try1.cpp). ([From chat.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/455993#455993))

Answer (score 5):

adding  `#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB`  at the beginning works.

Remember to link also boost libs listed in the errors (boost system in my case).

Answer (score 1):

This might be relevant https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4614

Comment: That refers to a bug supposedly fixed a couple of versions ago though.