# Boost undefined reference during compiling

Tags: c++, windows, boost, mingw

I am getting a compile error trying to compile a simple tester program from the documentation.

```
C:\DOCUME~1\A\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccRsXzHu.o:tester.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to     `_imp___ZN5boost6thread4joinEv'
C:\DOCUME~1\A\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccRsXzHu.o:tester.cpp:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to     `_imp___ZN5boost6threadD1Ev'
C:\DOCUME~1\A\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccRsXzHu.o:tester.cpp:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to     `_imp___ZN5boost6threadD1Ev'
C:\DOCUME~1\A\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccRsXzHu.o:tester.cpp:    (.text$_ZN5boost11this_thread18interruptible_waitEy[boost::this_thread::interruptible_wait(    unsigned long long)]+0x4a): undefined reference to     `_imp___ZN5boost11this_thread18interruptible_waitEPvNS_6detail7timeoutE'
C:\DOCUME~1\A\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccRsXzHu.o:tester.cpp:     (.text$_ZN5boost6threadC1IPFvvEEET_NS_10disable_ifINS_14is_convertibleIRS4_NS_6detail13thre    ad_move_tIS4_EEEEPNS0_5dummyEE4typeE[boost::thread::thread<void (*)()>(void (*)(),     boost::disable_if<boost::is_convertible<void (*&)(), boost::detail::thread_move_t<void (*)()> >, boost::thread::dummy*>::type)]+0x23): undefined reference to     `_imp___ZN5boost6thread12start_threadEv'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using mingw 4.5 and g++ 4.5.2 on windows. Boost version v1.4.8.

I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're not linking with boost_thread. Can you post your compile/link command?

Comment: This appears to be a linking issue.  Did you tell it to link to the appropriate libraries?

Comment: Yes I used g++ -o tester.exe tester.c. I also did it once with -I/location/to/boostfolder but that didn't work either.

Comment: You can't just give it a folder/directory. The -l command must specify the specific library file that you want to link to.

Comment: OK, than what lib should I link to?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you aren't linking to the boost libraries.

Boost doesn't come with windows since it isn't a standard library. You've got to download the headers and libraries, then include the headers in your project and link to the libraries at compile time. Since you're using g++, this means adding a -l line to your compile command. The -l line must be used with each specific library you want to use also, you can't just specify the boost directory.

[This page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) will help you get started on Windows and [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) will help you get started on *nix platforms.

Once you've compiled boost, then in your example, you should compile your program with

```
g++ -o tester.exe -Lpath/to/boost/libraries/ -lboost_thread tester.c
```

Comment: Yes I have looked at that page, although it isn't helpful at all. I have installed it with bjam and moved the header files into the right place so it can find it. But all that didn't do it.

Comment: It's not a header problem. It can definitely find the declarations of the boost functions in the header file. Because it's an "undefined reference", this means it's a linking issue. Try finding out the specific library that contains the function definitions for the functions you are trying to call, and then add -l/path/to/that/library to your g++ command.

Comment: You might also be missing the -L parameter which tells g++ where to look for libs. See the section in the *nix link I posted above called "Link Your Program to a Boost Library".

Comment: Oh ok. After you edited your post I got it. But now I still get an "cannot find lboost_thread error" from ld.exe. Even though I specified the libs directory.

Comment: So that means you've properly specified the library, but it can't find it. Maybe try setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH so it knows where to look for the libs? Try googling that error message, something should definitely come up.

Comment: It comes up with other -l errors though (everything buth -boost_thread). But to be sure, the libs/threads dir contains a build, doc, example, src, test and tutorial folder right? Could you tell me how to setup LD_LIBRARY_PATH if that would perhaps solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've got all your libraries linked properly.

Try putting this line first if your thread library is statically defined

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB
```

Also, check out  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705563/code-blocks-mingw-boost-and-static-linking-issues).