# Building Boost with Boost.Log "error: target { simple_event_log.mc. } has no type"

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I am trying to build Boost.Log ( http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html ). I added it to my boost sources and executed my usual boost build command.

```
b2 --build-dir="D:\boost\1.51.0\boost" toolset=gcc variant=release link=static threading=multi  runtime-link=static --build-type=complete
```

But nothing happened and I received this in the end:

```
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\generators.jam:1085: in ensure-type from module generators
error: target { simple_event_log.mc. } has no type
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\generators.jam:1319: in generators.construct from module generators
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:1495: in construct from module object(typed-target)@491
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:1298: in object(typed-target)@491.generate from module object(typed-target)@491
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:732: in generate-really from module object(main-target)@1871

D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:704: in object(main-target)@1871.generate from module object(main-target)@1871
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:258: in object(project-target)@474.generate from module object(project-target)@474
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:848: in targets.generate-from-reference from module targets D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:1217: in generate-dependencies from module object(install-target-class)@96
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:1269: in object(install-target-class)@96.generate from module object(install-target-class)@96
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:732: in generate-really from module object(main-target)@930 D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:704: in object(main-target)@930.generate from module object(main-target)@930
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:848: in targets.generate-from-reference from module targets D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:1217: in generate-dependencies from module object(top-level-target)@103
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:1269: in alias-target-class.generate from module object(top-level-target)@103
D:/boost/1.51.0/src\boostcpp.jam:391: in build-multiple from module object(top-level-target)@103
D:/boost/1.51.0/src\boostcpp.jam:376: in object(top-level-target)@103.generate from module object(top-level-target)@103
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:732: in generate-really from module object(main-target)@934 D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:704: in object(main-target)@934.generate from module object(main-target)@934
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:848: in targets.generate-from-reference from module targets D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:1217: in generate-dependencies from module object(top-level-target)@104
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:1269: in alias-target-class.generate from module object(top-level-target)@104
D:/boost/1.51.0/src\boostcpp.jam:391: in build-multiple from module object(top-level-target)@104
D:/boost/1.51.0/src\boostcpp.jam:376: in object(top-level-target)@104.generate from module object(top-level-target)@104
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:732: in generate-really from module object(main-target)@935 D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:704: in object(main-target)@935.generate from module object(main-target)@935
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2/build\targets.jam:258: in object(project-target)@42.generate from module object(project-target)@42
D:/boost/1.51.0/src/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:736: in load from module build-system
D:\boost\1.51.0\src\tools\build\v2/kernel\modules.jam:283: in import from module modules
D:\boost\1.51.0\src\tools\build\v2/kernel/bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-build from module
D:\boost\1.51.0\src\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

Could you, please explain what does it means or how I can see more error info? How did you build Boost.Log?

Comment: Did you download the archive from sourceforge? Boost.log needs to be fetched directly from the source repository, otherwise you get something very old and probably not functional if even build-able.

Comment: Could you, please give me a link to this repo?

Comment: See http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=199644

Comment: Does not work. I tried to build with bleeding-edge version and with trunk, always the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the problem can be found [here](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/supported_compilers.html):

> Second, at some point the library will require a Message Compiler tool
>   (mc.exe), which is not available in MinGW, Cygwin and MSVC Express
>   Edition. You have two options to settle the problem. In case of MinGW
>   and Cygwin you can use the windmc.exe tool, which is the analogue of
>   the original mc.exe. In order to do that you will have to patch
>   Boost.Build files (in particular, the tools/build/v2/tools/mc.jam
>   file) as described in this ticket. After that you will be able to
>   specify the mc-compiler=windmc option to bjam to build the library.

Here is a link to the [patch](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/attachment/ticket/4111/mc.jam.patch). Applying the patch and passing `mc-compiler=windmc` should solve the problem.

**Note:** Also, as noted on the comments in the [ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4111), you need to add `import mc ;` after `import fortran ;` in `tools\build\v2\tools\gcc.jam`.

**Here is what your mc.jam file should look like after applying the patch** (make sure your file looks like the following):

```
import common ;
import generators ;
import feature : feature get-values ;
import toolset : flags ;
import type ;
import rc ;

feature.feature mc-compiler : mc windmc : propagated ; 
feature.set-default mc-compiler : mc ; 

rule init ( )
{
}

type.register MC : mc ;


# Command line options
feature mc-input-encoding : ansi unicode : free ;
feature mc-output-encoding : unicode ansi : free ;
feature mc-set-customer-bit : no yes : free ;

flags mc.compile MCFLAGS <mc-input-encoding>ansi : -a ;
flags mc.compile MCFLAGS <mc-input-encoding>unicode : -u ;
flags mc.compile MCFLAGS <mc-output-encoding>ansi : -A ;
flags mc.compile MCFLAGS <mc-output-encoding>unicode : -U ;
flags mc.compile MCFLAGS <mc-set-customer-bit>no : ;
flags mc.compile MCFLAGS <mc-set-customer-bit>yes : -c ;

generators.register-standard mc.compile.mc : MC : H RC : <mc-compiler>mc ; 
generators.register-standard mc.compile.windmc : MC : H RC : <mc-compiler>windmc ;

actions compile.mc
{ 
    mc $(MCFLAGS) -h "$(<[1]:DW)" -r "$(<[2]:DW)" "$(>:W)" 
}

actions compile.windmc
{ 
    windmc $(MCFLAGS) -h "$(<[1]:DW)" -r "$(<[2]:DW)" "$(>:W)" 
}
```

**WARNING**

`boost-log\branches\bleeding-edge` fails to compile for me (gcc 4.7.1). I used the one in `boost-log\trunk\boost-log` for a successful build (built on 2012-09-05).

Comment: I have the same problem as the original poster (Boost 1.51.0 and MinGW GCC 4.7.0). Using boost-log\trunk and applying the patch unfortunately does not work. As soons as i remove the boost-log directories boost builds just fine.

Comment: @user573335: Try adding `import mc;` in `tools\build\v2\tools\gcc.jam` right after `import fortran ;` (I forgot to add that to my answer). This is also mentioned in the link to the ticket. If you have any other problems, please be specific about what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution, the `import mc;` solves the _..has no type_-error for me. Now only 4 targets have a problem building: `..boost_1_51_0/./boost/thread/win32/condition_variable.hpp:86: undefined reference to '__imp___ZN5boost11this_thread18interruptible_waitEPvNS_6detail7timeoutE'` (for the threading=single targets). Any idea where i should look for this?

Comment: @user573335: I get that error when I try to link boost thread statically ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705563/code-blocks-mingw-boost-and-static-linking-issues/3732505#3732505)) because it is configured for dynamic linking. However, I never had an error while building boost. I build it with `link=static,shared threading=multi` set.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
b2 toolset=gcc --build-type=complete threading=multi architecture=x86 address-model=32 --with-log define=BOOST_LOG_USE_CHAR --stagedir=.
```

It was working for me with Boost 1.51 and Boost::Log rev. 721

Comment: Still nothing, the same boost version, the same revision, but architecture=amd64 address-model=64