# How can I get rid of the __imp__ prefix in the linker in VC++?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm using libcurl and am getting the following sort of linker errors in VC++ 10.

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_strerror referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl curl_httpget(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?curl_httpget@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV12@@Z)
```

How can I get rid of that **imp** prefix in front of the function name? I am linking to the right lib, right path etc.

Comment: Related (or perhaps even duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704374/linking-error-lnk2019-in-msvc-unresolved-symbols-with-imp-prefix-but-should

Comment: Check out [this](https://dennisbabkin.com/blog/?t=intricacies-of-microsoft-compilers-the-case-of-the-curious-__imp_) and also [this](https://dennisbabkin.com/blog/?t=intricacies-of-microsoft-compilers-part-2-__imp_-and-__imp_load_-prefixes).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The `__imp__`  prefix appears whenever you are linking to a DLL. It does not appear when linking to statically linked libraries. Most likely the code is generated to be linked against a DLL import lib, but you have linked it with a static lib instead.

The prefix is added when you mark the imported function with `__declspec(dllimport)` - make sure your imports are not using this when not linking against a DLL.

Comment: yes I linked it with a static lib, but how do I link against a dll import lib ( and where is this option to link to a .dll set? ).

Comment: Dll is accompanied with a .lib. You link against the dll by linking against this accompanying .lib. It is impossible to know by name if the .lib is a static lib or a dll "trampoline", to know this you need to check inside of the .lib, but the .lib needs to match your imports.

Comment: Thank you @Suma! In my case there was an ifdef which led to the `__declspec(dllimport)` even though it was a dependency for a dll. The dependency was build as static library, but that didn't affect the ifdef.

Answer (score 22):

You have to add **CURL_STATICLIB** to *Preprocessor Definitions* at the properties of your projects in MSVC

Comment: In my case, I needed to #include <PlusConfigure.h>

Answer (score 12):

You are using a header file that defines the function prototype with the specifier evaluating to `__declspec(dllimport)`

You need to either redefine the statement that is evaluating to this (set it to nothing), or use a different header file altogether.

Typically you'll see code like this:

```
#ifdef FOO_EXPORTS
#define DLLSPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLSPEC __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

...

DLLSPEC bool foo(int bar);
```

Compiling the project with FOO_EXPORTS defined will use one mode and without it will use the other.

Answer (score 8):

If using wizard generated projects - check "Runtime settings" value in `project properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation` section.

By default it usually has "Multithreaded DLL" value. You need Multithreaded /MT and Multithreaded Debug /MTd values.

Comment: This worked when I was getting the error `LINK2019` `unresolved external symbol __imp_malloc` in Visual Studio 2015. It would compile without `#include <malloc.h>` or `#include <stdlib.h>` and crash, but when I added those I got the unresolved external symbol issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Suma mentioned, `<your_library>.dll` is normally accompanied by `<your_library>.lib`. Therefore if you get such error messages like

> `Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__<your_symbol> referenced in function ...`

it is highly recommended to check the Linker settings of your project.

In Visual Studio, just go for your project to

```
Properties -> Linker -> General
```

and check under entry `Additional Library Directories`, if the path to `<your_library>.lib` is defined there. If not, just add it.

Then check and define on

```
Properties -> Linker -> Input
```

under entry `Additional Dependencies` the probable missing `<your_library>.lib`.

The error message should disappear now.

Hope it helps?