# C++ Irrlicht Program doesn't link: "undefined reference to `__imp_createDevice'"

Tags: c++, 3d, irrlicht

My Irrlicht program doesn't link. The compiler I use is g++.

Code:

```
#include <irrlicht.h>

int main()
{
  irr::IrrlichtDevice *device = irr::createDevice();
  // And other init stuff
  while(device->run())
  {
    driver->beginScene();
    smgr->drawAll();
    guienv->drawAll();
    driver->endScene();
  }
  device->drop();
}
```

Linker output:

```
...
(path)/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to `__imp_createDevice'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Command line:

```
g++.exe -o "(Path)\Test.exe" "(Path)\Test\main.o"
..\..\..\..\..\..\MinGW\lib\libIrrlicht.a
```

The linker founds the library file. What's wrong?

Edit:
I made little experimenting. The result was, that when I comment `createDevice()`-line out, no linker errors will come. So that means, that linker founds all the other functions, i.e. `IrrlichtDevice::run()`.

Comment: stab in the dark - is it IrrLichtDevice or IrrlichtDevice you declare?

Comment: @Jimmy: Just a typo. In original code it's `IrrlichtDevice`.

Answer (score 1):

__imp_createDevice refers to a .lib file that is built for *dynamic* linking to an .so or .dll. [See this post and answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159353/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-imp-prefix-in-the-linker-in-vc)

Find the .lib that is built for static linking, or alternatively check if you have to specify a pre-compiler definition such as _IRR_STATIC_LIB_, IRRLICHT_STATIC or IRRLICHT_EXPORTS to have correct linkage.