# Visual Studio C++ 2013, linking errors with every single lib

Tags: c++, linker

I am trying to build some programs, but every single time I want to do it, it returns me linking errors. I am using external libs.

I have already added path to `/include` directory in *vc++ directories/include directories* and path to `/lib` in linker/general and added `*.lib` in linker/input.

I have also tried

```
pragma comment(lib, "path\\*.lib")
```

Unfortunately I still receive linking errors **1120** and **2019**.
I am unable to work with external libs such as `libcurl`and `opencv`.
`pragma comment` helps only with `ws2_32.lib`

Comment: Can you post _exact_ error messages and linker configuration?

Comment: You'd better post exact text of the errors and how many of them happen at least. Technically this error mean that symbol you or one of libraries is trying to use could not be found in any of the libraries from your input path, but it's hard to tell what exactly happens based on your input.

Comment: Error 5 error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplicationAAA\Debug\ConsoleApplicationAAA.exe ConsoleApplicationAAA
Error 4 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_cleanup referenced in function _main C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplicationAAA\maincpp.obj ConsoleApplicationAAA
And more errors 2019.
I am following this instruction:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to

@Predelnik

Comment: @MariusTrola Most likely you are running into something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159353/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-imp-prefix-in-the-linker-in-vc