# Static CRT link

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-linking, msvcrt, crt

im trying to build my project and I want to link the windows CRT statically, but I find some errors trying to linking it,

I've included in the linking list these ones:

- libcmt.lib
- LIBCPMT.LIB
- libucrt.lib
- libvcruntime.lib

but I get these linking errors, saying that these symbols are missing:

- __imp_copysignf
- __imp__aligned_free
- __imp__aligned_malloc
- __imp_modf
- __imp_modff

I've already added libucrt (which is where must be malloc functions but still giving errors), what lib am I missing?

EDIT: Im using Visual Studio 2017 15.4.4 targeting Windows 10 ver.10.0.16299.0

Comment: What is your Visual Studio / MSVC version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double-check that you have also set the [`/MT` compiler flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.110).aspx). If it is not set, it is possible that it defaults to dynamic linking setting. In that case, `_MT` preprocessor define is missing, which causes the compiler to use calls to dynamic runtime functions. You can see the `__imp__` prefix that normally [comes from DLL import libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5159395/737347).