# visual studio 2015 error unresolved external symbol __imp___fmode referenced in function _cpdf_open

Tags: c, dll, visual-studio-2015, fopen

i am getting below error on build after upgrading to visual studio 2015:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp___fmode referenced in
>   function _cpdf_open   .....ClibPDF.lib(cpdfInit.obj)  1
>   Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp___iob referenced in
>   function __cpdf_file_open ....ClibPDF.lib(cpdfInit.obj)   1
>   Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol
>   __imp___iob   ReportGenerator .......ClibPDF.lib(cpdfMemBuf.obj)  1    Error  LNK2001 unresolved external symbol
>   __imp___iob   ReportGenerator ........ClibPDF.lib(cpdfUtil.obj)   1

Please suggest how to remove the error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question has to little information and will probably not get an answer. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. So in this case, the minimal amount of code which produces this error in Visual Studio 2015 but does not in prior versions (if I understood you correctly)

Comment: I have code of my application that's whole code i was not getting error in prev version of VS....so how can I remove this error any thing particular needed plz let me know

Comment: You have to reduce the complexity of the problem. Write a simple standalone application. Compile it in both versions of Visual Studio. If you do not experience the error you described, add things step by from your real world application until you get the error. Your error seems to be related to the library ClibPDF. So write a small application which uses the same functions of ClibPDF as your big application and see if you can reproduce the error. This might help you narrow in the scope of the problem

Comment: If I understand the error message correctly, the function _cpdf_open function of the ClibPDF library uses a function called fmode which stems from another library which ClibPDF depends on ([the `__imp__` prefix seems to be generated by Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5159395/3082472). So maybe one of the libraries (ClibPDF or the unknown one it depends on) have been updated with Visual Studio and the other one not so they do not fit to each other anymore