# Updating to Visual Studio 17.4.0 Yields linker errors related to TLS

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors, visual-studio-2022

EDIT: Just for closure, this problem turned out to be due to a [bug in the linker](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/thread_local-causing-fatal-error-LNK1161/10199441).  Microsoft fixed it in release 17.4.3

I just updated my Visual Studio instance from 17.3.6  to 17.4.0.  Then I tried a clean build of my solution.  Suddenly one of my projects gives me linker errors

```
8>pch.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___tls_index_?init@?1??lazy_init_num_threads@internal@at@@YAXXZ@4_NA
8>pch.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___tls_offset_?init@?1??lazy_init_num_threads@internal@at@@YAXXZ@4_NA
8>C:\Users\jmole\Documents\Dev\Main\Solutions\..\Mobile\x64\Debug\net6.0-windows\mld_v143.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

This completely confuses me.  When I turn on verbose linking I see it finding all sorts of similar symbols in MSVCRTD.lib.  For example.

```
2>      Found _tls_index
2>      Found __dyn_tls_init
```

Anyone else encountering this?

Comment: `__imp___tls_index_` is not `_tls_index`. Your project seems to wrongly switch between using dynamic or static C runtime, and the corresponding warning should be raised in the log prior those errors.

Comment: Is that what that name means?   That it's trying to use a static function?  Because this is the exact same code that built with 17.3.6.   It has literally been a decade since I've needed to track down a non-obvious link error or decipher mangled names so it's tough for me to tell

Comment: Incidentally there does not seem to be any sort of warning about static vs dynamic.  We have warnings set to be errors in our build settings

Comment: It's a linker warnings, it's not affected by compiler settings.

Comment: Try to change Runtime Library in the project settings.

Comment: Would vote as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159353/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-imp-prefix-in-the-linker-in-vc

Comment: Still confused.  All projects share the exact same runtime library settings:  Multithreaded Debug DLL.  They all inherit it through the same property sheet.  This project does not override that.   More to the point, if I were linking improperly now it does not explain why this builds fine in 17.3.6 and not in 17.4.0

Comment: They seemed to switch to a newer format of project settings database. I got many settings reset to defaults after update. So, you can't be sure the project settings are the same as they were in 17.3.6. Fortunately I use cmake and just have to regenerate the project.

Comment: I do appreciate the replies.  (I hope I don't sound argumentative.)  Obviously, something has changed but I don't think it is project settings.    My C++ projects are Visual Studio only.  No CMAKE files, just straight up Visual Studio `.VCXPROJ` and  `.PROPS` files   Nothing about them has changed.  Even the interactive project-settings dialog, still tells me that the failing project is still using the same multithreaded runtime build settings.  I guess I'll have to try to re-build all my 3rd party libraries (just headers and .LIB files) and see if that helps.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using CMake, but regeneration of the project doesn't solve the problem. It seems to me it depends on the linked libraries, because I got this link error with a specific project only.

Comment: VS 17.4 updates STL. It can be a reason, does something with possible moved thread local storage code.

Comment: @ChrisStamm  The good news is we are very fortunate that they gave us the ability to go back to a previous version.  That's  what I had to do for now. I ran the installer, chose the "More" option and reverted back to 17.3.6.  Everything builds now.  I will have to fix it later after we do a release

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the file under `\Lib\site-packages\torch\include\ATen\Parallel.h` in your python environment and edit it by removing the inline implementation of `at::internal::lazy_init_num_threads()` leaving only the declaration. This will force your build to use non-inline import.
The issue is most probably in the way VS C++ handled inline exports having static variables - in this case `thread_local` one.

Perfect solution of course is rebuilding pytorch together with your extension (as would be the case with any C++ DLL "exporting" classes without really taking care about doing it in a safe ABI compatible way) but patching the include file is also OK here, it will just prevent the compiler from inlining the API and creating a reference to the local static `thread_local` variable that fails linking step later. The compiler will then use non-inline variant from the pytorch DLL and linker error will be done away with.

Comment: The version of PyTorch we are using now is just the already-built one downloaded from the official release.  If I were to edit that header file but not build or download anything new, you think that merely making this header file change would work and be safe?    I ask this first -- before trying it -- because in order to actually verify this I would need to update to version 13.4 again.  Then I would need to revert back if it caused problems.

Comment: (Meant version 17.4)

Comment: I have the same problem with pytorch C++ version and it solves my problem.

Comment: I was not able to actually make this change until today due to an impending software release.  However I made it and can confirm it solved the problem.  I still want to build it as was suggested first by @MSalters.  But this did fix the immediate issue

Comment: I'm using Anaconda, so in my case the file was at  `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\torch\include\ATen\Parallel.h`. Then I replaced everything from `inline TORCH_API void lazy_init_num_threads() {` down to the `}` with only this:
`TORCH_API void lazy_init_num_threads();`
and it worked.

Comment: Turns out it was a bug in the linker, fixed in version 17.4.3: 
  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/thread_local-causing-fatal-error-LNK1161/10199441

Answer (score 1):

The name mangling appears to point to `at::internal::lazy_init_num_threads`, which is a PyTorch function (a bit weird, but it might very well use thread-local storage). You may need to rebuild PyTorch with the same toolchain

Comment: Thank you.  That is exactly what I was guessing but you confirmed it.   And I would love to be able to build PyTorch.  We use the non-GPU-optimized version that you can just download.  That's what's giving me the link error.   I would love to able to build it properly, with GPU-optimization turned on.  Unfortunately my attempts to do so are not working out well. (It's why I had to go back to 17.3.6)  I can't even get CMake to generate me a proper VS solution.  Installed CUDA and all that.  But I guess this is the topic for a different post if I cannot figure it out myself.

Answer (score -4):

After updating to 17.4, please switch to LLVM for Visual Studio 2022 in Platform Toolset to avoid such errors in linking.

PS:
LLVM for Visual Studio 2017, 2019 and 2022:
[Visual-Studio-llvm-utils](https://github.com/zufuliu/llvm-utils)

Comment: This is not something you should do on a whim.

Comment: ...and certainly not something I'm going to do to fix a simple link error.