# LibTorch (PyTorch C++) LNK2001 errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, pytorch, libtorch

I was following the tutorial in LibTorch [here](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html#visual-studio-extension).

With the following changes:

- `example-app` => `Ceres`
- `example-app.cpp` => `main.cxx`

Everything worked until the CMake command `cmake --build . --config Release`.

It produced the following errors:

```
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___tls_index_?init@?1??lazy_init_num_threads@internal@at@@YAXXZ@4_NA [D:\Silverous Black\CPE42S2-CPE42S2\CPE 406\ProjectDumagan\src\Ceres\build\Ceres.vcxproj]
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___tls_offset_?init@?1??lazy_init_num_threads@internal@at@@YAXXZ@4_NA [D:\Silverous Black\CPE42S2-CPE42S2\CPE 406\ProjectDumagan\src\Ceres\build\Ceres.vcxproj]
D:\Silverous Black\CPE42S2-CPE42S2\CPE 406\ProjectDumagan\src\Ceres\build\Release\Ceres.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals [D:\Silverous Black\CPE42S2-CPE42S2\CPE 406\ProjectDumagan\src\Ceres\build\Ceres.vcxproj]
```

I don't believe these are from the changes I placed, since the problem is with the linking.

I also am trying to replicate this directly into Visual Studio. I am using Visual Studio 17 2022 which the [LibTorch extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YiZhang.LibTorch001) is not yet compatible with (Visual Studio 16 2019 is no longer available for install from the [website](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)).

The replication is through a blank C++ template (no starting files). And I have set the following macros:

- `LibTorchTarget` = `CPU` *specifies libtorch for CPU is to be used (useful for other macros*
- `LibTorchDir` = `C:/libtorch/` *directory where the **libtorch installation(s)** can be found (for multiple installations)*
- `LibTorchInstall` = `$(LibTorchDir)libtorch_$(LibTorchTarget)/` expresses to `C:/libtorch/libtorch_CPU/`
- `LibTorchInclude` = `$(LibTorchInstall)include/` expresses to `C:/libtorch/libtorch_CPU/include/`
- `LibTorchLib` = `$(LibTorchInstall)lib/` expresses to `C:/libtorch/libtorch_CPU/lib/`

And have put the *`Include`* and *`Lib`* macros at their respective `VC++ Directories` positions. As well as `$(LibTorchLib)*.lib` (`C:/libtorch/libtorch_CPU/lib/*.lib`) in the `Linker` > `Input` > `Additional Dependencies` to specify all the `.lib`s for linking (prevents a lot of `LNK2009` errors).

And lastly, I have put `start xcopy /s "$(LibTorchLib)*.dll" "$(OutDir)" /Y /E /D /R` command at the `Build Events` > `Pre-Link Event` > `Command Line` to replicate the *`if`* clause in the `CMakeLists.txt` in the tutorial (apparently to avoid memory errors).

Result is same exact error with a final `LNK1120` error:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___tls_index_?init@?1??lazy_init_num_threads@internal@at@@YAXXZ@4_NA    Ceres   D:\Silverous Black\CPE42S2-CPE42S2\CPE 406\ProjectDumagan\src\Ceres\main.obj    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___tls_offset_?init@?1??lazy_init_num_threads@internal@at@@YAXXZ@4_NA   Ceres   D:\Silverous Black\CPE42S2-CPE42S2\CPE 406\ProjectDumagan\src\Ceres\main.obj    1   
Error   LNK1120 2 unresolved externals  Ceres   D:\Silverous Black\CPE42S2-CPE42S2\CPE 406\ProjectDumagan\out\Debug_64\Ceres\Ceres.exe  1
```

I don't exactly understand the reason for the `LNK` errors, so if anyone could help that'll be really nice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look to: [Updating to Visual Studio 17.4.0 Yields linker errors related to TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74366357/updating-to-visual-studio-17-4-0-yields-linker-errors-related-to-tls)

You most likely need to rebuild PyTorch after MSVC update.

Comment: The ["delete implementation"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74437172/11505421) solution worked for me. Thank you for this.