# unresolved external symbol __imp__scanf referenced in function _main

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, wdk

I compile a driver with visual studio 2008 and I get this error:

```
unresolved external symbol __imp__scanf referenced in function _main
```

I don't use any lib and the main function look like this:

```
__cdecl main {

  .....
  scanf(...);

}
```

Note: I have other errors with other native functions such as:

```
unresolved external symbol __imp__printf referenced in function _main  
unresolved external symbol __imp__GetLastError@0 referenced in function _main
unresolved external symbol __imp__CreateFileA@28 referenced in function _main
...
```

The discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704374/linking-error-lnk2019-in-msvc-unresolved-symbols-with-imp-prefix-but-shoul) is not like my problem

Update:

I'm compiling a driver with WinDDK, I have pute the line in the **sources** file:

```
TARGETLIBS= $(SDK_LIB_PATH)\kernel32.lib
```

and much errors begin with **unresolved external symbol __imp__** are clean except those: __scanf and _printf. So what lib I must add to fixe them?
Thanks

Comment: The problem is you aren't using any lib, use stdio.h

Comment: Yes, i have stdio.h and windows.h but the problem still exist

Comment: check in C:\Program Files\<Microsoft Visual Studio Version>\VC\include that stdio.h exists?

Comment: Yes TheJoker, stdio.h still exist in the right place,
Please look  update

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704374/linking-error-lnk2019-in-msvc-unresolved-symbols-with-imp-prefix-but-shoul?lq=1

Comment: This is a linker error, not a compiler error, so it's nothing to do with missing header files.