# Why does -fsanitize=undefined cause "undefined reference to typeinfo"?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, shared-libraries, ubsan

The following test-case, reduced from a real-world application, fails to link with `-fsanitize=undefined` (using GCC 6.1.1) but links fine without it.  Can anyone tell me why?

It seems to have something to do with the combination of Qt/QObject, `-fvisibility=hidden`, and `-fsanitize=undefined`, but exactly where the problem lies is beyond me.

lib1.h:

```
#include <QObject>

class MyObject : public QObject
{
public:
    MyObject (QObject * parent = nullptr);
    ~MyObject ();

    void myMethod ();
};
```

lib1.cc:

```
#include "lib1.h"

#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))

EXPORT MyObject::MyObject (QObject * parent) : QObject (parent)
{
}

EXPORT MyObject::~MyObject ()
{
}

EXPORT void MyObject::myMethod ()
{
}
```

lib2.cc:

```
#include "lib1.h"

void test (MyObject * object)
{
    object->myMethod ();
}
```

Build steps:

```
LIBFLAGS="-fPIC -shared -Wall -Wl,-z,defs"
QTFLAGS="-I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -lQt5Core"

g++ -fsanitize=undefined -fvisibility=hidden \
 ${QTFLAGS} ${LIBFLAGS} lib1.cc -o lib1.so

g++ -fsanitize=undefined \
 ${QTFLAGS} ${LIBFLAGS} lib1.so lib2.cc -o lib2.so
```

Build output (from the final step):

```
/tmp/ccY7PHv4.o:(.data.rel+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for MyObject'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `-fsanitize=undefined` is a red herring.

You are only exporting the member functions of that class. In order to also export its metadata (like its typeinfo and potential v-table pointer) you need to export the *class*.

Try this

```
class EXPORT MyObject : public QObject
{
public:
    MyObject (QObject * parent = nullptr);
    ~MyObject ();

    void myMethod ();
};
```

Then you should not need to mark up the individual member functions.

Comment: ... which means a little more trouble, since the EXPORT now has to be defined in the public header, and needs to switch between dllimport and dllexport for the Windows builds.  But I've been doing some more reading, and this seems to be the recommended way to do it.

Comment: I believe you would need that regardless on windows, as it decorate symbol names. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704374/linking-error-lnk2019-in-msvc-unresolved-symbols-with-imp-prefix-but-shoul

Comment: Define "need". :)  Correct or not, we've been building this application on Windows for years without any sort of dllimport/dllexport in the public headers.  Marking individual function implementations, as in the example, was enough to make everything compile and run happily.

Comment: msvc has a much longer tradition of not exporting everything by default (i.e. requiring dllexport) and probably worked out all these edge cases in the late 90's. Perhaps to automaticall export class metadata if you export some parts of it. that's just my assumption though.

Comment: @Arvid  How can it be a red herring if it links fine without it?  I'm running into the exact same problem with code (third party compiled without RTTI) that compiles fine without ubsan but gives this error with ubsan.

Comment: @Arvid found the real answer and posted it - sanitize=undefined includes the vptr sanitizer which causes a dependency on the RTTI data.

Answer (score 18):

The answer to the actual question as asked is that `-fsanitize=undefined` is actually a collection of sanitizers including the `vptr` sanitizer.

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html

The `vptr` sanitizer is clearly marked as requiring RTTI, which other answers have described why it's not available.

To run all the tests *except* vptr, you can say

```
-fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize=vptr
```